# How can I know which python a pipenv venv is using?

Tags: python, pipenv

I am managing dependencies with `pipenv`. I have several python installs on my system.

**How can I know which python install has been used to create the venv ?**

I tried the following:

```
pipenv --venv
```

-> Just returns venv location, not python's original location

```
pipenv --py
```

-> Just returns location of python exe in venv, not original location

```
pipenv run python -V
```

-> Just returns version of python

Answer (score 3):

Inside the virtualenv folder, there is a `pyvenv.cfg` file which contains information about the Python interpreter used for the virtual environment:

```
home = /usr
implementation = CPython
version_info = 3.8.5.final.0
virtualenv = 20.1.0
include-system-site-packages = false
base-prefix = /usr
base-exec-prefix = /usr
base-executable = /usr/bin/python3
```

As explained by Python documentation: [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)

> Running this command creates the target directory (creating any parent directories that don’t exist already) and places a `pyvenv.cfg` file in it with a `home` key pointing to the Python installation from which the command was run (a common name for the target directory is `.venv`). It also creates a bin (or `Scripts` on Windows) subdirectory containing a copy/symlink of the Python binary/binaries (as appropriate for the platform or arguments used at environment creation time). It also creates an (initially empty) `lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` subdirectory (on Windows, this is `Lib\site-packages`). If an existing directory is specified, it will be re-used.

Comment: I only see the following in my venv folder: `Include/  Lib/  LICENSE.txt  Scripts/  share/  tcl/`. Are you running this on Unix or Windows ?

Comment: Ok, judging from base-executable, that's clearly Linux. Any chance you'd have a more portable solution ?

Comment: The ``pipenv.cfg`` does exist. I tried now in Windows. You need to go to the folder given by ``pipenv --venv`` and it should have that file.

Comment: This is my ``C:\Users\marcs\.virtualenvs\proj-D7QXKI2C`` folder in Windows: ``.gitignore   .project     [Lib]        pyvenv.cfg   [Scripts]    [src]``

Comment: That's weird, I don't see this file, I even updated `pipenv` and `--rm` the venv then reinstall to be suree. What the heck ? Which python version are you using ? In folder `C:\Users\Remi\.virtualenvs\louis-quickbooks-tools-ZEHp30br` I see `Include` `Lib` `Scripts` `share` `src` `tcl` `.project` `LICENSE`. Any thoughts ?

Comment: It is VERY strange. Python virtualenv documentation clearly states this cfg file is created upon starting a new virtualenv: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html - I don't know how your virtualenv knows where the Python interpreter is if this file does not exist. Can you do a full search on that folder?

Answer (score 0):

[`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) holds the path to the python executable that is currently running.

So you can find the path to your version using the following line:

```
pipenv run python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

Comment: ``sys.executable`` gives me path to the virtualenv interpreter (``C:\Users\marcs\.virtualenvs\proj-D7QXKI2C\Scripts\python.exe``), not the source interpreter where Pipenv is running.

Comment: To clarify, this is not the path I'm after. If the virtualenv was created with Python from `C:/Program Files/Python364`, and then symlinked/copied to the virtualenv location in `C:/users/Foo/.virtualenvs/proj-CHUEBDJ`, I'm after the first path, not the second one.

Answer (score -1):

On windows i can use which on powershell to get the path of pipenv.

```bsh
> which pipenv
... Source
... D:/programs/python/Scripts/pipenv.exe
```

Comment: I want location of original python.exe, not pipenv.

Comment: @Overdrivr yes but pipenv is installed in the  scripts folder of the original python.exe you just have to navigate the python installation.

Comment: Not true, I can install a virtual env with different python version with the flag `pipenv install --python 3.X` with the same pipenv. Pipenv-installed-python != venv-python

Comment: There is a difference between the version of python that pipenv is installed with and the versions of python that pipenv can use. Can you clarify which version you are interested in, because i gave you ways to find both.

Comment: I'm interested in the version of python that the virtualenv is using.